# Can websites view Ios device name?

Tags: device

I was wondering if websites can see (track) an Ipad Device name when accessing them?
For ex if Ipad is Called "Joe's Ipad" if there is any chance like an website to see that one person called Joe accessed the website?
Can they use any function like [UIDevice currentDevice].name; or this only works on simulator and apps installed on the device?

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you try to find your answer in the documentation? Where did you search?

Comment: An iphone is kinda the same as an ipad so I flagged it and as @AnimiVulpis said: there's a search box on the top right...